# Testing for new line in Python stdout

Tags: python, stdout

I have a script in which I'm having difficulty testing for a new line character coming from stdout of a remote command.

```
  OUT  = stdout.readlines()
  print OUT

  if ['\n'] in OUT:
    print "/disk/var/log/app directory deleted"
  else:
    for line in OUT:
      print line.strip()
```

The result of OUT is ['\n'] if a directory is deleted.  No matter what I try I can't get it to recognize ['\n'] in the if statement.

Comment: `if '\n' in OUT:` or `if ['\n'] == OUT:`?

Comment: @G_M, if ['\n'] == OUT: worked.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you are checking if the list `['\n']` (i.e. the list containing only one element, `'\n'`) is contained in `OUT`

[readlines()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readlines) returns a list of strings. It will never return a list which contains lists, so `['\n'] in OUT` shouldn't ever evaluate to true. You likely want to either do

`if OUT == ['\n']:`

OR

`if '\n' in OUT:`